# Android 5: headset's button mutes an active phonecall instead of ending the call

Tags: calls, mute, headset-controls

I recently bought a phone that came bundled with android 5. It is a ZTE Blade S6. I also have bought a Senheizer MM70i which has one button.

I am sure that the first few days if I pressed the headset's button during a phonecall the action would end the call.

Then I tried the jetAudio Basic music player and now it seems that when talking on the phone pressing the button mutes the conversation instead of hanging up.

Is there a way to revert that??

I have tried installing "Degauss Headset control center" but the application states that single button action is indeed to answer/end call, so I cannot alter the action through there.

Is there any other (perhaps low-level) way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

ok so apparently I can still end a call with a **long press** of the headset's button.

I wonder if there is any way to tweak these settings.

Comment: You can proably tweak it with something like a custom ROM or using GravityBox